# ¿ Cómo poner 4 botones centrados en pantalla de forma horizontal y separados un poco entre ellos?

Tags: android-layout

Estoy intentando colocarlo mediante relative y layout pero es un caos y no soy capaz:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="15sp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="50sp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Aquí te dejo una forma de conseguirlo he reutilizado parte del código que estabas usando estabas cerca de conseguirlo pero la clave es poner todos los botones en el mismo layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="50sp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Además también eso debe de estar en un `Linear layout orientatio:vertical`